# Eclipse for PHP - cached files

Tags: eclipse

I use this version of Eclipse for quick edits of php files for different websites I maintain. These files are not part of any project recognized by Eclipse, just random files I bring in and out of Eclipse.
Anyway, this is my problem: I open a file in Eclipse, I write "This", save it, and close it. I open the same file in Notepad (for example), I then edit it to say "This sucks", save and close the file. Then when I reopen the same file back in Eclipse, Eclipse only shows the updates I last made *in Eclipse*, i.e., "This". It doesn't reflect the changes I made in Notepad. How can this be fixed to where it doesn't cache files and opens files in their current state?

I tried Windows->Preferences->Remote Systems->File Cache and set Maximum Cache size to 0, and clicked "Clear Cached Files". This does not help, and I suspect this is dealing with something else (if it is, additional information on what this relates to would be appreciated).

> Eclipse for PHP Developers
>   Version: 1.3.2 - Helios Service Release 2

One last note. I thought `v. 1.3.2` seemed old, because I thought it was in `v. 3.*`, so I reinstalled Eclipse for PHP with the latest version on the Eclipse website and I ended up with the same version..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug of DLTK and according to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367757 it will be fixed on the next/future version.
Ver.1.3.2 is the version of EPP(Eclipse Packaging Project), it indicates the version of "Eclipse for PHP Developers" all-in-one package. It is too old anyway. You are using Eclipse 3.6.2(it's 3.7.1 now), PDT 2.2.1(it's 3.0.0 now), DLTK 2.0.0(it's 3.0.1 now), ... (as for PDT, newer doesn't mean better though)

FYI, there is a patched file for DLTK 3.0.1 (not for any other versions) about this problem at http://sourceforge.jp/users/atlanto/pf/eclipse/files/?id=435 pdt_tools.feature_patch.dltk.3.0.1.v20111005.zip

Comment: Thanks for the info; very helpful. Sorry for the late reply. Is there a newer version of EPP available that comes with those up-to-date packages? I'd like to apply that patch :)

Comment: PDT team dropped out of EPP at the release of Indigo, the package is no longer available.
It is necessary to install Eclipse Classic and then install PDT on it.(http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation#Eclipse_3.7_.2F_Indigo_.2F_PDT_3.0)
(Note that I don't recommend to do so because PDT 3.0 is too much buggy. I cannot use it without patches.)

Comment: BTW, thx for the link. Using the info there I figured out a work around to reboot Eclipse to clear/disconnect the `fileStore` they were talking about, and start fresh.

Answer (score 0):

try disable "Window->preference->Network Connections->Cache."
It's work for me, as before I have to use external tool (configure vim) to save php file, in eclipse juno.